# Why use AFNetworking instead of dispatch_async?

Tags: objective-c, ios, networking, afnetworking

Why should one use AFNetworking's async methods, when an async call can be done simply with GCD?

```
dispatch_async(bgQ, ^{

                //NSURLConnection code

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    //UI code
                });
});
```

Comment: Because AFNetworking is already finished and working, and your code is not :p

Comment: This is just something I typed in to ask the question, it's not a code that's in use :)

Comment: Thats an intelligent questions, @matt thanks for the answer

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is answered in detail at the top of the [AFNetworking FAQ](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ):

> While `NSURLConnection` provides `+sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` and  `+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`, there are many benefits to using AFNetworking:
>
> - `AFURLConnectionOperation` and its subclasses inherit from `NSOperation`, which allows requests to be cancelled, > suspended / resumed, and managed by an `NSOperationQueue`.
> - `AFURLConnectionOperation` also allows you to easily stream uploads and downloads, handle authentication challenges, > monitor upload and download progress, and control the caching behavior or requests.
> - `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and its subclasses distinguish between successful and unsuccessful requests based on HTTP > status codes and content type.
> - AFNetworking includes media-specific request operations that transform `NSData` into more useable formats, like JSON, > XML, images, and property lists.
> - `AFHTTPClient` provides a convenient interface to interact with web services, including default headers, authentication, > network reachability monitoring, batched operations, query string parameter serialization, and multipart form requests.
> - `UIImageView+AFNetworking` adds a convenient way to asynchronously loads images.